# Is possible to discard outer brackets in regex and consider inner bracket inside?

Tags: regex, pcregrep

I have many patterns with bracket enclosure,
I made a regular expression where is not considering brackets and just only
what is inside/between them, but exists a problem when the text within brackets
contain [] brackets too.

Thanks!

Regex: `(?<inside_value>(?<=\[).*?\[?(?=\]))`

For example,

```
A)   [ClusterReceiver[99]            ]
B)   [first-second-third-8050-exec-a       ]
```

From above, B) is working perfectly, but A) not

### What is being returned for every case (without quotes):

```
B) "first-second-third-8050-exec-a "
A) "ClusterReceiver[99"
```

### What is desired?

```
B) "first-second-third-8050-exec-a "
A) "ClusterReceiver[99]"
```

The problem is when exist `[ ]` bracket enclosure within outer `[ ]` enclosure.

The worst case is when exists that problem like A),
can you help me by giving a suggestion how to accept at least 1 bracket, in order to have A) as desired "ClusterReceiver[99]" ?

Comment: Maybe you want to require a whitespace before the `]`? Try `(?<inside_value>(?<=\[).*?\[?(?=\s+]))`

Comment: Wouldn't `(?<inside_value>(?<=\[).*(?=\]))` do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

For those example strings, as the result with your pattern for B) is already working as you desired, if you want to accept at least 1 bracket you can optionally match an inner `[...]` part

```
(?<=\[)(?<inside_value>[^\][]*(?:\[[^\][]*][^\][]*)?)(?=])
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\[)` Assert `[` to the left
- `(?<inside_value>` Start named group

  - `[^\][]*` Optionally match any char except `[` or `]`
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\[[^\][]*]` Match `[...]`
    - `[^\][]*` Optionally match any char except `[` or `]`
  - `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `)` Close the named capture group
- `(?=])` Assert `]` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lRgWNV/1)